# In python requests, get() misses content of HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap a certain website, by using BeautifulSoup and requests.
Here is what i did:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.semicom.co.il/catalogue/group/14954')
html1 = bs(r.content)
print html1.find('div', attrs={'class':'left_content'})
```

The answer is `<div class="left_content"></div>` but when i download the html file from Chrome i get the same element with it's content.

I tried to change encoding and use other libraries' the same problem happens

Comment: the contents of the `div.left_content` is possibly populated by javascript. use, mechanize or selenium for that kind of sites.

Comment: It's dynamically loaded content.  You'll need a more sophisticated scraping setup.  Look at selenium for instance